Problem with dockerized symfony project with psql database
Can't seam to migrate my entity to the database...
Docker-compose :
services:
  php:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html/app
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy

  db:
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "postgres"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5


volumes:
  pgdata:

Dockerfile (for symfony) :
FROM php:8.2-cli

WORKDIR /var/www/html/app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    unzip \
    libzip-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip pdo_pgsql

COPY --from=composer:2.6.6 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash && \
    mv /root/.symfony5/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony

COPY ./app/. .

RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader && \
    composer dump-autoload --optimize && \
    php bin/console doctrine:schema:create && \
    php bin/console cache:clear && \
    php bin/console make:migration --no-interaction && \
    php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["sh", "-c", "symfony server:start --no-tls --port=8000"]

the .env is indeed configure for "db".
I have a controller to test it :
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'test')]
    public function index(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setLogin('admin');
        $user->setFirstname('Admin');
        $user->setLastname('Admin');
        $user->setEmail('sgihgi');
        $user->setPassword('admin');

        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $userList = $entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();

        return new JsonResponse($userList);
    }
}

Yet, either way it alway show that :
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "user_id_seq" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT NEXTVAL('"user_id_seq"') ^
Saying that the Table user don't exist... So it must be the migration.
I can make the migration myself in the console of docker, it work. But I want to make it that it do itself each startup.

I don't think you should make migration in your dockerfile, you should commit them in your repository and just keep the doctrine:migrations:migrate
